# Using pretrained word embeddings to classify "pools" of words

Tags: python, nlp, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have seen many papers explaining the use of pretrained word embeddings (such as Word2Vec or Fasttext) on sentence sentiment classification using CNNs (like Yoon Kim's paper). However, these classifiers also account for order that the words appear in.

My application of word embeddings is to predict the class of "pools" of words. For example, in the following list of lists

```
example = [["red", "blue", "green", "orange"], ["bear", "horse", "cow"], ["brown", "pink"]]
```

The order of the words doesn't matter, but I want to classify the sublists into either class of color or animal.

Are there any prebuilt Keras implementations of this, or any papers you could point me to which address this type of classification problem based on pretrained word embeddings?

I am sorry if this is off-topic in this forum. If so, please let me know where would be a better place to post it.

Comment: Do you have the corresponding labels for these, a dataset perhaps? Because you can solve this without any deep learning and just word2vec as colours will already be clustered so will animals. You can just check which pool the word is most similar using dot product of vector and classify.

Comment: @nuric Yes, this is a very simple example to demonstrate the idea of my task, but my application is not as simple. I have a training set with lists of words (random order, each list containing around 100,000 words and all words in the list are not, for example, all about colors or animals) along with the class label, along with a validation set. Therefore I was looking for a deep learning solution, as simply looking at cosine similarity will not work.

Comment: You can train Word2Vec using gensim library. Other than that, you can use one-hot encoder and bag of words for the task because as you said the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point in creating that classifier would be to avoid any bias from the order of words in list. A naive LSTM solution would just look at first or last few words and try to classify, this effect could reduced by giving permutations of lists every time. Perhaps a simpler approach might be:

```
# unknown number of words in list each 300 size from word2vec
in = Input(shape=(None, 300))
# some feature extraction per word
latent = TimeDistributed(Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'))(in)
latent = TimeDistributed(Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'))(latent)
sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=-1))(latent) # reduce sum all words
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(sum)
model = Model(in, out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimiser='sgd')
```

where the reduced sum would avoid any ordering bias, if a majority of words express similar features of a certain class then the sum would also lean towards that.

Comment: What is `latent_dim`? Could you explain what the TimeDistributed layers do and why there are two of them (and not some other number)? Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, where are the word embeddings incorporated in this model? Sorry I am very new to machine learning.

Comment: So `latent_dim` is size of your hidden layers, number neurons if you will although I don't like that term. It is a *hyperparameter* something you fix before hand. TimeDistributed applies the Dense layer to every word in the list in this occasion. The word vectors are set by you as pre-processing, but you can look at [Embedding](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) as well.

Comment: What would a reasonable range of values for `latent_dim` be? If I added an embedding layer, can you confirm that it should be `in = Input(shape=(max_words_per_sentence, )); embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 300)(in); latent = TimeDistributed(Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'))(embedding)`

Comment: There is no literature on setting hidden values, I would start with 150. Yes, that looks right.

Comment: Perfect. Sorry for all the questions, but what does the second TimeDistributed layer do?